# Discord.js: Manually triggering events

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a basic moderation bot in `discord.js`, written in `node.js`. I need to run some tests on the bots but to do so, I need to toggle an event. I know that `node.js` has an `e.dispatchEvent(event)` but, to my knowledge, `discord.js` does not have a function like that.

I was wondering what the equivalent of that would be.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A Discord Client extends a Node.js EventEmitter, so you can use the [`EventEmitter#emit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) method to call listener functions attached to the event. For example...

```
// Assuming 'client' is a Client, 'member' is a GuildMember
client.emit('guildMemberAdd', member);
```

You can find a complete list of events normally emitted by a Client [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

In Discord.js, the [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) class is an extension of the Node.js [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) class. Therefore, you can use the [`EventEmitter.emit()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_eventname_args) method to emit events yourself.

Simple example:

```js
// Instantiate a Discord Client
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

// Attach a listener function
client.on('test', console.log);

// Emit the event
client.emit('test', 'These params', 'will be logged', 'via the listener.');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I must have missed it in the documentation.