# how to test event in discord.py

Tags: events, event-handling, discord, discord.py

lets say on_member_join event

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    # On member joins we find a channel called general and if it exists,
    # send an embed welcoming them to our guild
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="welcome")
    if channel:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description="Welcome to our guild!",
            color=random.choice(self.bot.color_list),
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        embed.set_author(name=member.name, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=member.guild, icon_url=member.guild.icon_url)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my event (I know it works) how can I test it in any way to execute command to emit the event (not manually by adding and removing someone)?

[something like .emit on_member_join @user   where arg1 is event and if needed arg2 is mention or id of channel ]

Any command for that ?

something like [Discord.js: Manually triggering events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478980/discord-js-manually-triggering-events) but in discord.py not in JavaScript

Comment: Can you explain further what you're trying to achieve? It's not making much sense.

Comment: well there is (Discord.js: Manually triggering events)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478980/discord-js-manually-triggering-events] is there option in discord.py to do the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there isn't official support in the discord.py api to do something like that but you can always make a command in the cog like follows:

```
@commands.command()
async def test_join(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
   await self.on_member_join(member)
```

Technically there is a way to probably do it that isn't documented...

Line 131 in [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py). I will not offer addition support for that because it isn't documented.