# Making discord.js send a message to channel on command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot send a message to a channel in all servers that it is in when updated. My idea is that I will trigger this manually whenever I update my bot. For example, I would like to have it send a message such as "Updated bot to version 2.03. Update log: (changes made in the update)". This is the code I currently have:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var Long = require("long");

const getChannel = (guild) => {
    // get "original" default channel
    if(guild.channels.cache.has(guild.id))
      return guild.channels.cache.get(guild.id)
  
const jimmyChannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "jimmybot");
if (jimmyChannel)
  return jimmyChannel;
return guild.channels.cache
 .filter(c => c.type === "text" &&
   c.permissionsFor(guild.client.user).has("SEND_MESSAGES"))
 .sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position ||
   Long.fromString(a.id).sub(Long.fromString(b.id)).toNumber())
 .first();
 }
  
  // I found this as an example but I'm not sure if it will work
  client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    const channel = getChannel(member.guild);
    channel.send(`text`);
  });

client.login('token');
```

My question is how do I call this manually instead of it sending the message whenever a user joins the server?

Comment: You might wanna use `message` event for this. Check if the author is you, then map through servers and find the channels you want to send a message in. Honestly, I wouldn't do that as your bot can easily be rate limited (if in a lot of servers) for sending too many messages that may result in your bot being banned from Discord. What you can do to stimulate your users is to add an announcement channel in your server and ask them to subscribe to the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this properly...

Client is actually just a variation of a Node.js EventEmitter, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478980/discord-js-manually-triggering-events).

This means that you can trigger the events of your own accord, and so here you could do your own 'custom' EventEmitter and trigger it of your own accord.

Ex code paired with message event emitter. I know that it's generally frowned upon to put an event emitter inside of another, but it was the only solution I could find.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
token = 'XXX'

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Fully functional and initialized!');
});

// Attach a listener function
client.on('test', console.log);

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    if (msg.content === 'emit event') {
        // Emit the event
        client.emit('test', 'This will be printed on the console');
    }
})

client.login(token);
```